# What are the possible features I can consider for short term wind speed forecasting?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, artificial-intelligence, svm

I am designing a machine learning model using LSSVM that can be use to forecast the short term wind speed in wind farms. What are the important features that I should consider in order to have an efficient predictive model?

Comment: The current wind speed.

Comment: This question is too broad ... so far.  What factors are you considering already?  What is "short-term"?  What metrics do you have from the surrounding area on which you can draw?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_power_forecasting#Prediction_of_meteorological_variables

Comment: Short term prediction is predicting 30 minutes to several hours ahead. it is a time-scale that is widely studied by researchers. Researchers on wind speed forecasting consider two types of variable: one which includes external variables such temperatures, pressure and humidity etc, generally called exogenous variables, and the other that doesn't and only considers indigenous variables such as zonal wind speed, meridional, directional etc or there could be more I don't of. So what are the features, indigenous variables, that must be considered to effectively train your model?